# Increment %z hex numbers with VIM?

Tags: vim, hex

Is there a way to increment `%z` hex numbers with VIM? Typically I can do this by just doing `ctrl + a` for normal numbers. But unfortunately I am using a old school system that uses `%z` rather than `0x` to denote hexadecimal numbers. I've tried

```
Set nf=hex
```

But that sadly only works for `0x` hex numbers. Anyone come across this before? I haven't found much on the google machine.

Comment: Where is the `%z` format from?  It looks like vim will only natively support the `0x` prefix for hex numbers, so your best bet to do this might be to globally replace the `%z` with `0x` then do your macro or whatever to increment before switching the prefix back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this `%z` prefix; but I tried a quick and dirty function that increment numbers like %z0f; is it what you want? You should then be able to add a mapping to it (but not  itself since it is used in the function!) like `:map <C-p> :call MyIncrement()<CR>`

Of course you should customize it according to your needs; the line 17 reset the position of the cursor after incrmeenting; you may want to replace `l:c` with `l:b` (or maybe even `l:a`) and choose what you like the most.

```
function! MyIncrement()
  let l:l = line(".")
  let l:c = col(".")
  let l:a = 0
  let l:b = 0

  let l:s = search('%z[0-9a-f]\+', 'bcW',l:l)
  if l:s == l:l
    let l:a = col(".")
    let l:s = search('%z[0-9a-f]\+', 'ecW',l:l)
    let l:b = col(".")
    if ((l:a<=l:c)&&(l:c<=l:b))
      call cursor(l:l, l:a+2)
      silent exe "normal i 0x\e\<C-a>"
      call cursor(l:l, l:a+2)
      silent exe "normal 3x"
      call cursor(l:l, l:c)
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @oobivat comment:

```
:map \a Fza0x<ESC><C-a>Fzlxx
```

now, `\a` -- (Please choose a better key) will:

- find  `z`in the left  (`Fz`)
- add `0x` (`a0x<ESC>`)
- incremente hexadecimal (`<C-a>`)
- remove `0x`  (`Fzlxx`)

Comment: This solution however only works if you actually are on the right position; it is easy to have a wrong behaviour as soon as you use it anywhere else with the character "z" being on the same line. From this point of view, the other solution is more robust since it actually checks whether the current position follows the required format.

Comment: @Baruchel, I have not thought about that! You are probably right (if it works in robust way it is pure luck). Could you point any case where it produces a wrong behavior?

Comment: Type the line "# Initialize register x to %z1b" as if it were a kind of comment in your code; put your cursor on the % which is likely to happen in real use and try your mapping!